# UPS monitoring software for Linux, FreeBSD and Solaris

Tags: linux, solaris, freebsd, ups

Looking to configure auto shutdown for my servers once the UPS battery reaches a certain state. We have MGE / EATON Pulsar M3000 UPS units, and a heap of servers running Ubuntu, FreeBSD and Solaris - oh and windows.

I am all very new to this, so I'm unsure if there is a standard program which I should be using. 'Nut' has been suggested. Has anyone had any experience with this?

Any other recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It might not be the right solution for your situation (NUT as mentioned by the other answer is *right* for you), but a common solution for *nix system is [apcupsd](http://www.apcupsd.org/). It links to most UPSs (they have a list) and will do remote communication (to shutdown multiple systems connected to the same power source). Also, several big server equipment brands are actually rebadged APC units (such as HP UPSs).

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of doing this is Network UPS Tools - http://www.networkupstools.org/ as you mentioned but I don't really know much about *nix/bsd so there may be others. NUT does the job and is compatible with some Eaton units.

Although I've also read people mentioning using a windows machine plugged into the ups to inform *nix boxes they should shut down but I wouldn't know where to start on that.